# conditional min and max date in uib-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-datepicker

I want to add an `uib-datepicker` in an `ng-repeat`. Each item has it own min and maxdate, so I want to conditional set this to the datepicker.

Currently I have this, but it isn't working:

```
<p class="input-group">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="task.datePlanned" is-open="popup.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions($index)" close-text="Sluiten">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="openDate()">
           <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
       </button>
    </span>
</p>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.dateOptions = function(index){
    return {
        maxDate: new Date($scope.campaign.tasks[index].endDate),
        minDate: new Date($scope.campaign.tasks[index].startDate)
    }
}

$scope.openDate = function(){
    $scope.popup.openend = true;
}

$scope.popup = {
    openend: false
}
```

I get an `Error: [$rootScope:infdig]` error at the `min` and `maxdate`.

Is there a way to add conditional dates to the picker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each item has it own min and maxdate, so I want to conditional set this to the datepicker.

If the requirement is to set a separate min, max for each item, you could expand the object definition in the tag itself, like this:

```
<p class="input-group">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" 
       uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" 
       ng-model="task.datePlanned" 
       is-open="popup.opened" 
       datepicker-options="{
                     maxDate: task.endDate,
                     minDate: task.startDate
                 }" 
       close-text="Sluiten">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="openDate()">
           <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
       </button>
  </span>
</p>
```